# Installing Superuser on Android User Debug Build (no su binary found)

Tags: android, linux, apk, root, superuser

I'm currently doing lab work on an upcoming device and I've hit a wall on this particular one.

I can't say the model number, but it's running Android 5.1 and the build is LMY47D

It's a user debug build - so I have the SU binary and busybox installed, and I am perfectly capable of running any and all su commands.

[image: SU Commands Available]

I have the SU binary located in "system/bin/" and it's linked to "/system/xbin/." It has root access and the correct privileges (I think). Also you can see that busybox is installed.

[image]

Where I am having the problem is installing superuser and a few other apps.

I installed the apps to the "system/app/" folder with the privileges 755 along with appdel.apk and appdel2.apk (The ones that I need to give root access too)

Here is a snapshot of the "/System/app" folder.

[image]

As you can see, everything is there with root privileges, but when I try to access the application, nothing is working.

How do I give these applications Root Access?

As a side note, I can't flash or reload this ROM. Kingo root and IRoot just about bricked the phone. The superuser that I am trying to install is 2.46, which is the same superuser that the guys at Nexus Root are using on their LMY47D devices.

This is one of the guides that I have been following (among others): http://pocketnow.com/2012/10/10/root-without-unlocking

Thank you guys

Comment: What you need please give a brief description about you need

Comment: install a superuser application that can give other apps root access manually.